# aws access from ec2 instance to its own public ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I configure ec2 instance with elastic-ip on AWS with custom VPC, pinging to its own elastic-ip not returning any reply,
Adding the IP to the security-group didn't resolve it. 
any idea?

Comment: Can you post your security group rules too?

Comment: @mozzi zadok Could you confirm that internet gateway attached with your custom VPC and whether EC2 instance was launched in public subnet?

Comment: internet gateway is attached, but I'm not sure what do you mean by public subnet, security group allow access to all its own id and public ip

Comment: Ping uses ICMP. By default ICMP is blocked on AWS. Have you enabled ICMP in the security group?

Comment: I enable all traffic, can you guys approve that you able to ping to your public IP from within the instance?

Comment: Look in the route table for the subnet your host is in.  It should have an entry for 0.0.0.0/0 pointing to your internet gateway.  Does it?

Comment: @ kenlukas, it have

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works.

To test this, I did the following:

- Connected via SSH to a Linux Amazon EC2 instance, using its public IP address
- Did a `ping` to its public IP address -- it failed
- Added Inbound **All ICMP - IPv4** permissions from `0.0.0.0/0` to a security group associated with the instance
- Did a `ping` to its public IP address -- it worked!